# Calculate the different photography parameters

Tags: c#, .net, metadata, photo

I'm currently working withing C# to put images in my api database (school project) and I want to store ISO, Aperture and Shutterspeed as well. Now those are stored in the metadata as APEX or EXIF and not the 'normal' values. I've already did some research and found a way to calculate the Aperture: `var value = Math.Round(Math.Pow(2,apexValue/2),1);` but it makes rounding fault for some (5.7 instead of 5.6, 22.6 instead of 22, ...) and so I was wondering if there is an easy way to convert those to the values know by people (aperture to f-stops, shutterspeed to seconds, iso to iso values)?

At this point, I'm looking into [Property Item Descriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/windows/desktop/gdiplus/-gdiplus-constant-property-item-descriptions) but I'm a bit confused by them because if we take Aperture for example: the property is called: PropertyTagExifAperture and so you would think that it is an Efix value but the description states: Lens aperture. The unit is the APEX value. So what is it then, Efix or APEX?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What do you mean by "convert them"?  Convert them to what?

Comment: That's not really the output of your code, because `Math.Round` returns an integer.
Anyway, the reason is that the Exif ApertureValue will have been rounded, see [link]http://web.mit.edu/graphics/src/Image-ExifTool-6.99/html/faq.html#Q4[/link] at point 4.

Comment: @Amy - the poster wants to convert the aperture value to an F-Number

Comment: @iakobski `Math.Round` returns a `decimal` or `double`.  None of the overloads returns an integer.  [This particular overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Math_Round_System_Double_) does indeed return a `double`, since `Math.Pow` always returns a `double`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the single parameter version returns the nearest integral value.

Comment: Have you searched for any ready-to-use libraries? For example I found: https://github.com/fraxedas/photo